# external ip either goes pending or the assigned ip is not working

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, macos-mojave

I deployed my service with the command `kubectl expose deployment hotspot-deployment --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080` 
and the external-ip was pending:

```
hotspot-deployment   LoadBalancer   10.104.104.81   <pending>     8080:31904/TCP   1m
kubernetes           ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          18m
```

After searching for it's solution, I assigned the external ip to my service with: 
`kubectl patch svc hotspot-deployment -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer", "externalIPs":["192.168.98.103"]}}'` 
and the ip got assigned:

```
hotspot-deployment   LoadBalancer   10.106.137.71   192.168.98.103   8080:31354/TCP   12m
kubernetes           ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>           443/TCP          35m
```

Now, when I try to hit my service using the URL: `http://192.168.98.103:8080`

The page doesn't open. I tried debugging with 
`minikube tunnel`
, it shows:

```
    machine: minikube
    pid: 33058
    route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 192.168.99.105
    minikube: Running
    services: [hotspot-deployment]
    errors: 
        minikube: no errors
        router: no errors
        loadbalancer emulator: no errors
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can **not** expose your service in minikube with `LoadBalanser` type because it intended to use cloud provider’s load balancer

You should rather use `service` command:

```
minikube service hotspot-deployment --url
```

Then open url in your browser